# How can I check which installation of python I'm using and remove all others?

Tags: python

I was trying to import pandas, and  I have Anaconda installed but when I run it, it says `ImportError: No module named pandas`

So in terminal, I typed `which -a python` and the output was `usr/bin/python`

Then I typed in the command `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` and my output was:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66736 May  5  2016 /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    925 Oct 23  2015 /usr/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66736 May  5  2016 /usr/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 May 19  2016 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

I run my scripts by creating a PATH variable in terminal and running the script in terminal. I wanted to know which python I'm using and what/how I can rid of the other ones that are unnecessary. So for example, I would write something like `export ENGINE=/home/username/Software/...` and then each time I wanted to execute a python script in terminal I just call it like `$ENGINE test.py`

Comment: As a warning: it's not a good idea to remove the default system version of Python, as it is used by package management and other maintenance scripts in a lot of Linux distributions. Things will stop working if you try removing the default one. It sounds like you really want virtualenv: https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: As someone who's wrecked a system by removing the default Python, I can attest that you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: Which one is default python?

Comment: How are you running python? Are you running the copy of python provided by anaconda?

Comment: I think so, When I go to the anaconda > bin  there are two documents, python2.7 and python2.7-config, but it says that both these files are documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Anaconda and the root environment, just run `python -V` in your terminal and it will print the version

Comment: I found that I'm running 2.7, so what else exactly should I remove from my computer so that my import pandas can work?

Comment: if you are using Anaconda you can create and manage virtual environments. Each environment have it's own python version and it's own installed dependencies.

Comment: Don't uninstall any python version directly from your OS. It can broke all the system.

Comment: how would I manage the virtual environment? And how can I make sure my python scripts are using Anaconda

Comment: what do you mean by "using Anaconda" , i assume you want to use jupyter notebook or something installed in Anaconda?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. I want to use pandas, but I don't know how because it gives me an error saying 'no module named pandas.' I was looking at SO similar questions and they said it might be because you are running multiple versions of python, so I tried checking with the commands in my original question. So I'm unsure how to uninstall or what to uninstall to get pandas to work

Comment: ok, no problem. If you want you use pandas you have to install it by pip or any other package manager for python. Anaconda is a GUI to manage conda that is a virtual environment manager. So my suggestion is that if you want to use a specific version of python and don't mess with the other installed, use a virtual environment Anaconda can create a new one and this new one you can select the python version and which packages you want to install as pandas. You can read more about creating virtual env with anaca conda here [link](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html)